# Security on Linked Server on google cloud

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, google-cloud-sql

My question is as follows: I have local servers with SQL Server database and I have a server in google cloud also with SQL Server database.

I link these servers through the Linked Server functionality of SQL Server itself, where one server can see the other.

This link is OK and working.

My big question is regarding security, when making this link between my local servers and the google-cloud server, how vulnerable am I to the network?

What is my security risk in doing this?

Comment: This sort of question is not typical for SO since it does not have an exact answer. Maybe someone will reply to this, but generally this sort of question is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

The Linked Servers function uses a driver named [OLE DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to connect. How vulnerable you're  really depends on the version of said driver, if you're using the [last version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) it supports TLS 1.2 which ensures that the information is private and secured.

The most notable risk resides on how secure your Google Cloud SQL account, besides that the GCP is a secure environment for your DB, as mentioned in the [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#data-storage-and-replication):

> Cloud SQL customer data is encrypted when stored in database tables, temporary files, and backups. External connections can be encrypted by using SSL, or by using the Cloud SQL Proxy.

> Google encrypts and authenticates all data in transit at one or more network layers when data moves outside physical boundaries not controlled by Google or on behalf of Google.